# Karma and AGM maps (Angular4+)

Tags: angular, google-maps, karma-runner

I'm correcting the karma tests i've set up for an angular 4+ project (new components's import etc)...

Among the various libraries I'm using there's `Angular-Map` (aka [Agm](https://angular-maps.com) (Non-premium) ).

1. Is there someone else who has used this library and knows how to set it up for karma tests?
2. Is there a specific way or do I need to test it using the map api secret as if i were using it in a regular fashion?